# Windows 8 - Wifi option gone from connection options. Can connect via Physical Connection only

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

**I don't see any Wifi option in Windows > PC Settings:**
[image: No Wifi option in Windows > PC Settings]

**No Wifi Option in Network And Sharing Center:**
[image: No Wifi Option in Network And Sharing Center]

**I Uninstalled and Reinstalled Ralink Wifi Drivers, its showing up as installed in Control Panel:**
[image: Control Panel : Ralink]

**But Nothing in Device Manager:**

[image]

**Can someone please help me get my Wifi Back?**

Comment: Many laptops have a hardware switch for the WiFi, or a software switch that is inside some vendor proprietary software. What is the make and model of your PC?

Comment: @DavidPostill it's an HP pavilion g6 laptop